# querySelector causes error while getElementById does not

Tags: javascript, frontend

`document.getElementById("sub_but").addEventListener("click", calculatePrice);`

I have this line in JavaScript that works as it is supposed to.

`document.querySelector("sub_but").addEventListener("click", calculatePrice);`

But this line shows an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error. The script is placed at the end of the body before the closing tag and the button is part of HTML and not generated by code.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your selector is wrong: `document.querySelector("sub_but")` -> `document.querySelector("#sub_but")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prepend `#` in `querySelector` in order to fetch an element by Id:

```js
document.querySelector("#sub_but").addEventListener("click", calculatePrice);
```

The reason behind it is that it uses [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).